# How to get MapLibre Layers properties?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, maplibre-gl

Please help, I have been suffering since 5 days.
How can I get all `layer Ids`of a `MapLibre` map ?

```
function addLayer(map, options, layer) {
    let currentLayer = edges_data_api.find(
    element => element.edge_id === layer.feature.properties.edge_id)
    map.setPaintProperty('lines', 'fill-color', ['interpolate', ['linear'],
    ['get', currentLayer.lanes], 0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 5, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'])
    }
```

Here is how I defined the map with `MapLibre`

```
map.on('load', function() {
    map.addSource('lines', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: data
    });

   map.addLayer({
        'id': 'lines',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'lines',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
        'fill-color': '#4682B4',
        'fill-opacity': 0.8,
        }
    });
   map.setPaintProperty('lines', 'fill-color', ['get', 'color'])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Style Specification](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/style-spec/layers/)

> A style's layers property lists all the layers available in that style.

So you can get map's layers from the style object using [Map.getStyle()](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/api/map/#map#getstyle)

```js
map.getStyle().layers
```

Answer (score 0):

As i know, there are no api for *getAllLayers()*. So u should keep list of layers' ids by you own.

```
//global variable
const layerIds = new Set()

map.on('load', function() {

    layerIds.add('lines') //keep list of ids without duplicates

    map.addSource('lines', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: data
    });

   map.addLayer({
        'id': 'lines',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'lines',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
        'fill-color': '#4682B4',
        'fill-opacity': 0.8,
        }
    });
   map.setPaintProperty('lines', 'fill-color', ['get', 'color'])
})


//You can iterate your list ids where it is needed
layerIds.forEach(value => {//action here})
```

Comment: lots of thanks. It's not working. I have nothing when I console.log(value)

Comment: In this case, the `layerIds.forEach(value => {//action here})` would need to be called after the layers are added in the map `load`

Answer (score -1):

This returns an array containing the ids of all layers:

```js
Object.keys( map.style._layers )
```

But beware: the code accesses private fields both of Map and Style, therefore it may, however unlikely, no longer work for new versions of MapLibre.